# How to hide TabBarIOS

Tags: react-native

When I push the navigator to my MessageThread component the TabBarIOS is still there in the bottom. I want to hide this every time I go to another page.

this is my tabbarios:

```
<TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
                <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
                  title="Messages"
                  iconName="ios-chatboxes-outline"
                  selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Messages'}
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                      selectedTab: 'Messages',
                    });
                  }}>
                  <NavigatorIOS style={styles.container}
                    initialRoute={{
                      title: 'Messages',
                      navigationBarHidden: false,
                      component: MessagesRecent
                  }}/>
                </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
                <Icon.TabBarItemIOS
                  title="Groups"
                  iconName="ios-people-outline"
                  selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Groups'}
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({
                      selectedTab: 'Groups',
                    });
                  }}>
                  <NavigatorIOS style={styles.container}
                    initialRoute={{
                      title: 'Groups',
                      navigationBarHidden: false,
                      component: Groups
                  }}/>
                </Icon.TabBarItemIOS>
            </TabBarIOS>
```

onPress event:

```
goToChat: function(){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'Messenger',
      component: MessageThread,
      passProps:{
        navigator: this.props.navigator
      }
    });
  }
```